# How do i define and select random user in wordpress database config in wp-config.php?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

```
$randomuser = array("user","user1","user2","user3","user4","user5");
shuffle($randomuser);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', $randomuser);
```

How do i make the above code to work in wp-config.php ? Thanks.

Comment: [`array_rand($randomuser)`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Comment: doesn't seem to work in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set how many random users you want to get in 2nd argument too:

```
$random_users = array_rand($random_user,5); //gets 5 random users from array
```

Comment: i only want to random select 1 user and define as DB_USER as above.  The code i made above doesn't seem to work.